# using awk to list out report according to Type

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, awk

i am trying to use `awk` to do a payroll report but i am not very sure how to go about doing. Have tried the following but doesn't seems to be working properly. I am stuck because the code i written managed to sort out the "Salaried" but still list out the other data instead of only name and Pay.

EDIT: i've tried out the calculation part.. but does not know how it works too

need the result to show as :

1) sort out the type 'Salaried" , Hourly and Commissioned

eg:

```
Salaried:
Frank    $2333
Mary     $1111

Total salary: $3444
----------------------
Grand Total: $3444
```

code:

```
 echo "***** payroll report ****"
 awk -F',' '{print $2}' | grep "Salaried" $PAYROLL

 totalcost=0
   salariedcost=0
   for i in `grep $j $PAYROLL | cut -d "," -f6`
   do
    let "salariedcost = salariedcost + $i"
   done
    echo "Salaried Cost: \$${salariedcost}"
    let "totalcost = totalcost + salariedcost"
   echo "Total Cost: \$$totalcost"

   echo -en "Hit [Enter] to return to main menu..."
   read
```

.txt file :

sequence as followed : [id], [name],[title],[phone],[type],[pay]

```
3,Frank,CFO,91111453,Salaried,2333
1,Mary,CEO,93424222,Salaried,1111
5,John,Sales user,9321312,Commission,9999
7,Chris,Admin,98888753,Hourly[122]
```

Comment: @jkshah just to check if i want to compute grand total for all "Salaried, Commission, and Hourly" how can i do it? not  too sure how to declare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F',' '{print $2}' | grep "Salaried" $PAYROLL
```

This tells `grep` to open the file named in `$PAYROLL`, search for the string `Salaried`, and print the full lines when it finds it. `grep` the exits, and `awk` is killed by a `SIGPIPE`. What you were probably going for:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' "$PAYROLL" | grep Salaried
```

Note slight changes to quoting.

But `awk` does pattern matching just like `grep`:

```
awk -F, '/Salaried/{print $2}' "$PAYROLL"
```

For the whole program you'll want something like this:

```
awk -F, '
# Before processing the first line, print out the header
BEGIN {
    print "Salaried:"
}
# Lines matching Salaried
/Salaried/ {
    # Print name <tab> salary
    print $2 "\t$" $6

    # Add their salary to our salary total
    salaries += $6
}

# Every line, add cost to total
{ 
    total += $6
}

# After processing all lines
END {
    # Print the salary total, separator, and grand total.
    print "Total Salary: $" salaries
    print "--------------------"
    print "Grand total: $" total
}' file.txt
```

Comment: hey thank you for the help, regarding the calculateion i've tried the code but can't work too..

Comment: @Alien Updated with the whole program.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `awk`

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "Salaried:"} $5=="Salaried"{total+=$6; printf "%s\t$%s\n", $2, $6} END {printf "Total salary: $%s", total}' $PAYROLL
```

Output:

```
Salaried:
Frank   $2333
Mary    $1111
Total salary: $3444
```